# Compiling and Running Java and C++ Programs from Other Java Program in SandBox environment

Tags: java, sandbox

I am developing an application in Java that compiles and runs other programs (written in C++, C, Java, ...) that are submitted through a website which I am also developing. I am compiling and running the programs using windows CMD, now my question is, is there a way to run these programs safely? I was reading about Java Sandbox but I believe this only works with java apps?

Thanks

Comment: The "sandbox" usually refers to applets running in browsers. "App" is usually short for application, and applications generally have the same capabilities as the user running them without special measures. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html

Comment: Thanks Gus! well I read about the SecurityManager however, I am not sure if it can be applied if I am using CMD to run the applications, am I right?

Comment: yes, a java "sandbox" (aka, using the SecurityManager) will have no benefit for protecting against externally executed code.

Comment: I was merely clarifying what the "sandbox" was. (thus the comment not an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do what you want (securely) is to use some sort of virtualization technology to launch these programs in isolated vms (e.g. virtualbox and vmware).

as noted in the comments, the java SecurityManager will not protect any code run outside of the java vm.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is there any virtualization plugin for eclipse that will help me with this?